# Tensorflow: OutOfRangeError tf.train.string_input_producer is closed and has insufficient elements

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

---

I have been trying the following code segment to experiment with the input pipeline

```
import tensorflow as tf 
with tf.Session() as sess:

   filename = ['/data/read/A.JPG', '/data/read/B.JPG', '/data/read/C.JPG']    
   filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename, shuffle=False, num_epochs=5)

   reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
   key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)    
   tf.local_variables_initializer().run()    
   threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
   i = 0
   while True:
      i += 1

      image_data = sess.run(value)
      with open('/data/read/test_%d.jpg' % i, 'wb') as f:
         f.write(image_data)
```

Running the above code gets the following error message, looks like it is caused by `filename_queue` generated by `string_input_producer`. But I am not clear what's the problem and how to correct it. Thanks.

```
caused by op 'ReaderReadV2', defined at:
File "test_input.py", line 12, in <module>
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py", line 193, in read
return gen_io_ops._reader_read_v2(self._reader_ref, queue_ref, name=name)
File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 411, in _reader_read_v2
queue_handle=queue_handle, name=name)
File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_1_input_producer' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](WholeFileReaderV2, input_producer)]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `queue runners` should always be used along with `Coordinator`.

> The Coordinator helps multiple threads stop together and report
>   exceptions to a program that waits for them to stop.

They also catch and handle exceptions generated by queues, including the `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` exception, which is used to report that a queue was closed.

So your training should be:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

   filename = ['/data/read/A.JPG', '/data/read/B.JPG', '/data/read/C.JPG']    
   filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename, shuffle=False, num_epochs=5)

   reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
   key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
   tf.local_variables_initializer().run() 

   # Create a coordinator, launch the queue runner threads.
   coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
   threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
   i = 0
   try:
       while not coord.should_stop():
          while True:
            i += 1
            image_data = sess.run(value)
            with open('test_%d.jpg' % i, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(image_data)

   except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
       # When done, ask the threads to stop.
       print('Done training -- epoch limit reached')
   finally:
       coord.request_stop()
       # Wait for threads to finish.
   coord.join(threads)
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code:

```
filename = ['/data/read/A.JPG', '/data/read/B.JPG', '/data/read/C.JPG'
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename, shuffle=False, num_epochs=5)
```

create a filename queue which will allow to dequeue each of the 3 files exactly 5 times. See the doc (highlight is mine):

> `num_epochs`: An integer (optional). **If specified, `string_input_producer` produces each string from string_tensor num_epochs times before generating an `OutOfRange` error.** If not specified, `string_input_producer` can cycle through the strings in `string_tensor` an unlimited number of times.

After 15 dequeue operations in your infinite loop, the exception `OutOfRangeError` is then raised. If you don't specify `num_epochs`, the loop will run until you stop it with another way.