# TensoFlow: when num_epochs specified in train.string_input_producer(), tf.train.shuffle_batch() always throw OutOfRange

Tags: tensorflow

I write a simple program to try out reading data in batch functions in TensorFlow but encountered a problem:

I created 6 simple csv files; each file contains 3 records like:

```
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1
1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1
1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,1
```

(the first 4 columns are feature and the fifth column is the label.)
so totally 6 files have 6*3=18 records.

I try to read the files into 3 batches of 6 records/batch using `reader`, `batch` or `shuffle_batch`. When I don't specify `num_epochs` in `string_input_producer` the code works fine. But when I specify `num_epochs` the `batch` or `shuffle_batch` always throws `OutOfRange error`. The `current_size` is always zero...

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

csvFiles = os.listdir('./data')
csvFiles = [i for i in csvFiles if i[-4:]=='.csv' ]
csvFiles = ['./data/'+i for i in csvFiles]

print(csvFiles)

fileQ = tf.train.string_input_producer(csvFiles,shuffle=False,num_epochs=3)
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key,value = reader.read(fileQ)
record_defaults = [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0]]
col1, col2, col3, col4, label = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
feature = tf.stack([col1, col2, col3, col4])
feature_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([feature, label], batch_size=6, capacity=100, min_after_dequeue=1) # num_threads=3,

with tf.Session() as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess,coord=coord)

    try:
        for i in range(3):
            featureBatch, labelBatch = sess.run([feature_batch, label_batch])
            print(featureBatch)
            print(labelBatch)
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:    
        print("Done reading!")
    finally:
        coord.request_stop()

coord.join(threads)
print("**END**")
```

the output of `OutOfRange` error is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEXTt.jpg)

please note the error was throwed when `shuffle_batch` was first called. I think it means not a single record could be read.

and even I changed the code to just read one record it throwed the same error:
`l,f=sess.run([label,feature])`

This is a very simple code. Wonder what's wrong with it? Thank you very much!

Comment: and for the code I have another question about coord.

I saw some sample code don't specify coord parm in: tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)

but if I remove coord statements my program will go into dead loop.

I wonder how the other sample code works without specifying coord??

Comment: Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44874244/outofrangeerror-for-tf-train-string-input-producer/44875392#44875392

Comment: Hi Vijay thanks for your input! However I don't think mine is duplicate to that question. My problematic code does use "coord". And if I don't specify num_pochs it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the string doc of the method:

> num_epochs: An integer (optional). **If specified, `string_input_producer`
>     produces each string from `string_tensor` `num_epochs` times before
>     generating an `OutOfRange` error.** If not specified,
>     `string_input_producer` can cycle through the strings in `string_tensor`
>     an unlimited number of times.

The `OutOfRange`error basically reproduces the `StopIteration` error Python raises when iterating on a list. See for example this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14413978/4282745).

Answer (score 0):

After reading the other sample code, I found we need add:
   tf.local_variables_initializer().run()
to initialize the variables. (Even I don't know why num_Epochs=3 needs be initialized.)

Now the code can work.